# Opening SQLite db in C# in VS2017

Tags: c#, sqlite, connection

I have recently started learning C#. I am using youtube, MS academy and O'Reallys C# book (big one).

I have tried adding a SQLite database to a simple program - just to see if I can store, alter and read data from it.

I am getting a System.ArgumentException error, telling me, my connection.Open(); has an invalid signs in it.

Here is the code I am using:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=z:\test.db; Version=3;"))
        {
            using (var command = new SQLiteCommand(connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
```

I am not sure, what I am doing wrong.
I am using the Nuget package called System.Data.SQLite - it is however installed for the whole solution, not just as reference to the Program.cs. Would that matter?

I am using Visual Studio 17 on a 64 bit win 10 computer.

Hope someone knows, where I am failing. :)

Best regards

Brian.

Comment: z:\ should be  z:\\   . Right now, your string would be parsed as Z:<TAB>est.db

Comment: I found it as you were typing. Thanks anyway. :D

Comment: You're welcome, happy coding ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your string contains a special character `\t`, which gets interpreted as a `TAB`.

You should either use a verbatim `string` by prefixing `@` or escape the \t with two backslashes:

```
@"Data Source=z:\test.db; Version=3;"
```

or

```
"Data Source=z:\\test.db; Version=3;"
```